# Scala: failing a Future based on a Future#collect

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, future

`WS.post` returns a `Future[Response]`, but I want a `Future[Data]` so I'm using `Future.collect` for that purpose.

```
private def getDataFuture(data: String): Future[JsValue] =
    initAuthenticatedRequest().post(body).collect {
    case response => response.json(0)
  }.recoverWith {
    case NonFatal(_) => getDataFuture(data)
  }
```

However, sometimes `response.json(0)` returns a bad value because I receive an empty json. I expected this to cause the Future to fail and do the `recoverWith`, but that didn't happen.

Do I need to do branching within the collect case?
How can I handle this more elegantly? I imagined that Future would have provisions for this.

Comment: The debugger shows 'JsUndefined({} is not an array' for the value

Comment: val r: Future[JsValue] = WS.url("").post[String]("").map(response => response.json). Why you use `response.json(0)`. Сan you better describe the problem (example for response and what do you need at the end)

Comment: `response.json(0)` refers to the first element in the json array but sometimes the server sends an empty json due to a known bug

Comment: so, you need only first element of json array. What should happen if json is empty?

Comment: If you want send `post` to server while json is not array, try `response.json.as[JsArray](0)`. `as[JsArray]` will throw `JsResultException` if json is not `JsArray`.

Comment: The Future never comes at all when I try `case response => response.json.as[JsArray].productElement(0).asInstanceOf[JsValue]`

Comment: can you show valid response example? if response is `JsArray` you should use `response.json.as[JsArray](0)` to get first element

Comment: typo: the last  `JsArray` is `JsValue`. A valid response may be of the form [{first: 1}, {second: 2}]

Comment: according response example `(response.json.as[JsArray](0) \ "first").as[Int]` returns 1, and `(response.json.as[JsArray](1) \ "second").as[Int]` returns 2. Docs: [Traversing a JsValue structure](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson#Traversing-a-JsValue-structure) - "simple path" and "index lookup"

Comment: Yes, but I'd like the `recoverWith` to trigger when the server returns an empty json

Comment: It will be so. `response.json.as[JsArray]` casts response to `JsArray` or throws exception ([source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsReadable.scala#L18))

Comment: Ooh sorry, you're right. I got confused because occasionally my Future times-out. But that seems to be another problem.

Comment: important note for such using `recoverWith` - may be infinite loop and stack overflow because of recursion call if server will be unreachable.

Comment: I've got `Await(Await.result(getDataFuture(data), 5.seconds)`. I think that should handle it, right?

Comment: I dont know how you want use results, but in any case blocking is not good.

Comment: My next call is to validate and convert the json into a class object. I don't think I can proceed in this case without the JsValue

Comment: If you have some problem with convert - create question, or join [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102438/discussion-between-andrey-ladniy-and-kliew)

Comment: I could use a callback on the Future, but the server employs asynchronous execution. If my data mining app used callbacks, my log data could be out of order by timestamp.

Comment: I dont understand last comment. Can you describe your problem otherway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use

```
initAuthenticatedRequest().post(body).map(_.json.as[JsArray])
```

`json.as[JsArray]` casts json to `JsArray` or throws exception, which can be handled with `recoverWith`